# application stopped in Android /SQLITE ERROR/

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

Yesterday the application was working normally, and i didn't edit my codes. But now its not working.
the logcat is

```
close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/[myproject]/databases/MyDB' 
android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1943)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1007)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:986)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1051)
at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:770)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:221)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:157)
at mn.emondo.parliament.DBAdapter.open(DBAdapter.java:46)
at mn.emondo.parliament.ProfileActivity.onCreate(ProfileActivity.java:46)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You need to check in `ProfileActivity.java:46` and `DBAdapter.java:46` .You forgot to call database call function ,which may be you have use in 'ProfileActivity.java:46' to open database.

Comment: Show you code will give us more specification how you do Database open and close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you open the database and cursor you must close these two before exiting from the class or activity.
db.close();
cr.close();

please use this.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't Closed the Cursor. It is Written in your ERROR.

```
Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
```

So as as i can't see your code, just check you haven't Closed your Cursor.

Or Try to Clean your Project and Re-Build it.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to [`close()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#close%28%29) your database; the next time it is opened you'll receive a `DatabaseObjectNotClosedException` exception.

Answer (score 1):

If it was working previously and not now ,,
try changing the version name of the database,,,

even after if it doesn't work , then change the version name and the database name .

Answer (score 1):

Try this method when you finish fetching data from database..
When you open database you need to call db.open() and when you finish your database work you need to call close() method.
use following method.

```
db.close();
```

and you must call to open database from your Activity.java